# Stubbing all methods of a groovy class?

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, mocking, stub

Is there an easy way to stub ALL methods of a groovy class? In one of my tests, I need to make sure a certain code path doesn't touch a service at all.

That is, I want to mock every method like this:

```
[meth1: {-> fail(msg)},
 meth2: {-> fail(msg)...}] as MyService
```

Is there an easy way to stub and intercept all methods of all argument types and perform some uniform action like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simple way I can think of is something like this:

```
MyService.metaClass.invokeMethod { String name, args ->
  assert false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `MyService` is an interface you can do this:

```
MyService stub = {Object[] args -> fail(msg)} as MyService
```

I'm not sure if this works when `MyService` is a class